# Wait for multiple Fluxes to complete and return combined result

Tags: spring-boot, java-stream, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have 3 different functions which take a similar type of input and emit a flux of the same type

```
    Flux<Response> ruleSet1 = checkRuleSet1(data);
    Flux<Response> ruleSet2 = checkRuleSet2(data);
    Flux<Response> ruleSet3 = checkRuleSet3(data, storeId);
```

1. CheckRules1, CheckRules2, CheckRules3 all complete processing at different times!
2. Data object sent to CheckRules1, CheckRules2, CheckRules3 has Id.
3. CheckRules1(),CheckRules2(),CheckRules3() has parallel processing inside so the result is not returned in same order

This is the Model call for Response class:

```
public class Response {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private int id;
    @JsonProperty("isEligible")
    private boolean isEligible;
    @JsonProperty("failureReasons")
    private ArrayList<Reason> failureReason = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I would like to combine the failure reason codes from all the above 3 fluxes based on id:

**Suppose checkRuleSet1 check produces a tuple**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "isEligible": false,
    "failure Reason": [
      {
        "FailedId": 1,
        "reason": "some thing1"
      },
      {
        "FailedId": 2,
        "reason": "some thing2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "isEligible": false,
    "failure Reason": [
      {
        "FailedId": 1,
        "reason": "some thing1"
      },
      {
        "FailedId": 2,
        "reason": "some thing2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Suppose checkRuleSet2 check produces**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "isEligible": false,
    "failure Reason": [
      {
        "FailedId": 3,
        "reason": "some thing3"
      }
      
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "isEligible": false,
    "failure Reason": [
      {
        "FailedId": 4,
        "reason": "some thing4"
      },
      {
        "FailedId": 5,
        "reason": "some thing5"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Suppose checkRuleSet3 check produces**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "isEligible": false,
    "failure Reason": [
      {
        "FailedId": 7,
        "reason": "some thing7"
      }
      
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "isEligible": false,
    "failure Reason": [
      {
        "FailedId": 8,
        "reason": "some thing8"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**I want the resultant flux to be**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "isEligible": false,
    "failure Reason": [
      {
        "FailedId": 1,
        "reason": "some thing1"
      },
      {
        "FailedId": 2,
        "reason": "some thing2"
      },
      {
        "FailedId": 3,
        "reason": "some thing3"
      },
      {
        "FailedId": 2,
        "reason": "some thing7"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "isEligible": false,
    "failure Reason": [
      {
        "FailedId": 1,
        "reason": "some thing1"
      },
      {
        "FailedId": 2,
        "reason": "some thing2"
      },
      {
        "FailedId": 4,
        "reason": "some thing1"
      },
      {
        "FailedId": 5,
        "reason": "some thing2"
      },
      {
        "FailedId": 8,
        "reason": "some thing1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

`isEligible` fail should be of XOR value of 3 fluxes

Comment: `Flux.concat(ruleSet1, ruleSet2, ruleSet3).groupBy(Response::getId).map(gf -> gf.collect(Collectors.reducing((a, b) -> { /* reduction logic */ })));`. Note that you must take care to return different object than `a` or `b`. You should also take care to create a defensive copy of `failureReasons` because there will be multiple threads acting upon it since the sources are different.

Comment: You can use `c = Boolean.logicalXor(a.isEligible(), b.isEligible());` for performing xor.

Comment: And what have you tried?